# Haskell if-construct that returns nothing on `else`

Tags: if-statement, haskell, null, void

is there a way where a construct like (pseudo code):

```
test (a,b) = if a > 10 then a else null
```

in Haskell. If you map over a list I can use `filter` to do this, but I would like a similar construct using `if then else`.

Comment: What will you use this construct for? I suspect there is another way to solve your original problem.

Comment: @Madderote - As for pure expressions, this is not feasible, you have to return something in any case. However, in an action context, you might want, depending on the value of a predicate, to _do_ something or to do nothing. This is the [when function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:when), which has definitely no _else_ clause. Example: `when (debugMode)  (putStrLn $ DEBUG: x = " ++ (show x))`

Answer (score 10):

Haskell has no null references, but that doesn't mean that you can't model the presence or absence of values. You typically use the `Maybe` type for that, with the data constructors `Just` for values and `Nothing` instead of null.

You could write your function like this:

```
test (a,b) = if a > 10 then Just a else Nothing
```

Here's how to interact with it:

```
Prelude> test (11, "foo")
Just 11
Prelude> test (10, "foo")
Nothing
```

The type of the function is:

```
test :: (Ord a, Num a) => (a, b) -> Maybe a
```

It obeys the rule that both the `then` and the `else` branch returns a value of the same type - in this case the type is `Maybe a`.

Comment: Basically you _always_ return something in `if-else` block, and that something is same type in both branches.

Comment: Perhaps preferrably written `test (a,_) = a <$ guard (a>10)`.

Comment: @Ackdari, Mark Seemann, thanks. Am aware of the Maybe type, but this in general does solve the issue, considering a `Nothing` is a value too, and still requires filtering if I'd like to gain a list of `Just`s. What I am looking is that in a condition there will be either a value or really nothing is returned. It looks like @Popara is right and Haskell's if-then-else construct always returns something.

Comment: @Madderote I'm not sure I understand what you want to do, but if you want to both `map` and `filter` a list, you can do just that, *or* you can `map` with the above `test` function and then throw away the `Nothing` values with [catMaybes](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:catMaybes).

Comment: @Madderote You can't simply *not* return a value. Even in a language like Python, where you might write `def test(a, b): if a > 10: return a`, the function `test` *still* returns `None` implicitly. In Haskell, you just have to be explicit about what you are writing. (leftaroundabout's suggestion just hides the explicit return of `Nothing` behind the `<$` operator and the `guard` function.)

Comment: @Madderote "What I am looking is that in a condition there will be either a value or really nothing is returned. " Haskell doesn't allow this. And `if...else` must always evaluate to a value.

Comment: @Chepner/leftroundabout: Ok. Understood. Then I will accept Mark Seemann's solution of mapping/filtering over the Just's as an answer. Seems the most logical way then. Hiding the `Nothing` is not exactly what I prefer to do. Thanks for the discussion and help.

Answer (score 2):

To filter a list with a predicate you could simply use `filter` like this

```hs
filter (>10) myList
```

but if you want to have a function that relectes in the output if the value was ok and returns the value, you can use the [`Maybe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html) type

```hs
test :: Int -> Maybe Int
test a = if a > 10 then Just a else Nothing
```

then you could filter with this function like this

```hs
catMaybes 
  $ map test
  $ myList
```

But if you just want to filter a list of values then you should use the first version with just a predicate that returns `Bool`

Comment: `catMaybes` from `Data.Maybe` would be a better alternative to `map fromJust $ filter isJust`, in my opinion. Because it's not using the potentially unsafe `fromJust` (I appreciate that it's safe _in context_).

Answer (score 1):

All answers are good.. I just would like make a small addition by reminding that while pure functions are not able to do that, Haskell allows us to perform impure actions as well, for instance in the `IO` monad. There, we are more relaxed on doing such things .

```
test :: (Num a, Ord a, Show a) => (a,b) -> IO ()
test (a,b) = when (a < 10) $ print a

λ> test (11,"boru") -- nothing happens
λ> test (9,"boru")
9
```

kind of.

Answer (score 0):

`if...else` is an expression in Haskell and must always evaluate to a value. Furthermore, both branches must evaluate to a value **of the same type**. So the `else` branch must evaluate to the same type as `a` for your code to work.

In the case of `filter`, the result must be a list. We can implement `filter` using `if...else`. The idea here is that if the condition is true, then we want to include the element in the resulting list. If not, then we want to continue filtering on the rest of the list.

```
filter _ [] = []
filter f (x:xs) = if f x then (x:f xs) else f xs
```

Note that in both cases, **the result is a list**. We remove an item by **not including it in the returned list**.